# How do I scale my apache server with virtualhosts?

Tags: apache, configuration, apache2.2

My server has gotten busier these past few weeks and I'm trying to keep up w/ the demand but am doing something wrong in trying to keep up with the demand. I have 2 domains: www.example.com and api.example.com and the following httpd.conf file:

```
MaxSpareThreads 3
MinSpareThreads 1
ServerLimit 1
ThreadsPerChild 15
WSGIDaemonProcess api python-path=/path/to/python2.7 processes=8 threads=15

<VirtualHost *:18546>
    ServerName api.example.com
    ServerAlias api.example.com
    KeepAlive Off
    WSGIDaemonProcess api.example.com processes=1 threads=20 inactivity-timeout=100 display-name=[api]httpd
    WSGIProcessGroup api.example.com
    WSGIScriptAlias / /path/to/wsgi.py
    ErrorLog /path/to/error.log
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:18546>
    ServerName www.example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    KeepAlive Off
    WSGIDaemonProcess www.example.com processes=1 threads=20 inactivity-timeout=10 display-name=[www]httpd
    WSGIProcessGroup www.example.com
    WSGIScriptAlias / /path/to/wsgi2.py
    ErrorLog /path/to/error2.log
</VirtualHost>
```

When I look at my processlist in linux I see the following processes:

```
[www]httpd
[api]httpd
/path/to/api/
/path/to/api/
/path/to/api/
/path/to/api/
/path/to/api/
/path/to/api/
/path/to/api/
/path/to/api/
```

The api subdomain seems to be spawning children but the www subdomain does not. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: Using Apache 2.2.25

Comment: I don't for sure, but I see you have `WSGIDaemonProcess api ... processes=8` at the top of the config, while your other `WSGIDaemonProcess` directives have `processes=1`.  THis is probably why there are 8 api process and 1 of the other processes (i.e., because that is what you asked Apache to do).

Comment: Yes, there is 1 process for www and 1 for api. But why are there 8 threads for api and none for www?

Comment: I ended up ditching apache for nginx. Much easier to configure, IMO.

Answer (score -1):

You ask for `threads=20` and `process=1` for both but you also ask for only 1 process (`ServerLimit 1`) with a maximum of 15 threads (`ThreadsPerChild 15`) -- default is usually 64. **So you ask for more than what you set in limits**.

When you have less than 1 spare thread another one will be created, and deletion of threads will happen if you have more than 3 spare threads, so as soon as you go near the number of 15 threads, Apache is certainly creating and deleting threads, a lot.

You did not alter the ThreadLimit default (which is high), so if you have a lot of people requesting your server you may grow to a big number of threads (if every one is very active), and when you have more than 20 threads you maybe have some of them connected to the subdomain.

I'm maybe wrong, but it would be logical.

Comment: I now have several downvotes... without remarks. Maybe just to make some emphasis on the fact that using Nginx is a better solution? Common, a response about Apache performance that would always be 'use nginx' would be as dumb as the 'jQuery for all' responses from early SO era. That was an Apache question, not an Apache versus Nginx survey.